# Why should I use "About box" instead of using a form to display about Information in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio

I have a confusion,

Why should I use an "About box" item provided by the Microsoft Visual Studio to display the information about my app instead of using a "Windows Form" item to do the same, while I have found the inherent About box difficult to be used as compared to the "Windows Form"?

Comment: Some applications don't care much about GUI skinniness, and they can use the standard supported form for convenience.

Comment: It is just for convenience.  Personally, I always use a custom form, which I can then layout however I choose.  Forms are cheap and easy to build, the convenience of "About box" is small and the gain even smaller.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no reason as far as I know, other than convenience. It already has a layout, and the version information - so you don't have to write it.

It's damn ugly though.

Comment: f 'ugly describes it better IMO. +1